# Detect VPN via C# or api

Tags: c#, wmi, vpn

I have a win app and I need to be able to help troubleshoot VPN issues that might be blocking my app. First I need to be able to tell if they have VPN or are connected to VPN.

I saw an older post on the same question (7months ago) with nothing definitive so I was curious if there were newer ideas or thoughts.

I suppose I can query the system folders for things like VPN or cisco but... it seems a little hack'ish.

Ideas or thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Look for the presence of another style of adapters besides Ethernet, list all of the network connections and their types, unless they have a 56.6k modem, if they have a PPP style adapter, it would strongly indicate a VPN tunnel.